# Which of the followings are norms on $\mathbb R^2 ?$

Tags: normed-spaces

1. $||x||_1=|x_1|+|x_2|$, where $ x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^2$
2. $||x||_2=\displaystyle\sqrt {x_1^2+x_2^2}$, $ x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^2$
3. $ ||x||_{max}=max\{||x||_1,||x||_2\}$,$ x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^2$
4. $||x||_{min}=min\{||x||_1,||x||_2\}$ ,$ x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R^2$

I know that 1,2 are true as satisfy all conditions of norm, how  to prove or disprove 3,4 ?

Thanks.

Comment: 4 is not a norm since $||x||_{min}=min\{||x||_1,||x||_2\} = 0$ does not imply $x=0$.

Comment: 3 *is* a norm. Usually denoted by $\mathcal L^\infty$-norm.